# Extract all values from div but individually

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, element


Stock_Symbol=input("Enter the symbol of the stock\n")
Stock_URL="https://ticker.finology.in/company/"+Stock_Symbol
response=requests.get(Stock_URL)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
Current_Price = soup.find("div", {"id":"mainContent_clsprice"}).find("span", {"class": "Number"}).getText()
CP=float(Current_Price)
print("Current Price of\t"+Stock_Symbol+"\tis\n",CP)
Market_Cap= soup.find("div", {"id": "mainContent_updAddRatios"}).find("span",{"class":"Number"}).getText()
MC=float(Market_Cap)
print("Market Cap of\t"+Stock_Symbol+"\tin Crores is\n",MC)
No_of_Shares=MC/CP
print("No of shares of\t"+Stock_Symbol+"\tin Crores is\n",No_of_Shares)
EPS= soup.find("div", {"id":"mainContent_updAddRatios"}).find("span",{"class":"Number"}).getText()
print(EPS)
```

In the above code, the `<div>` with `id="mainContent_updAddRatios"` contains some values which I want to extract individually such as *EPS*, *Earnings*, *Debt* etc.

I am not able to find a way to do so - symbol I am using is SBIN

Comment: Good answers require good questions, please help make your problem comprehensible to all by improving your question with details and expected output. Thanks

Comment: Your question needs to include the input, the expected output, and your current output. We have no idea what’s going in to your program to be able to tell what should happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** *Question and expected output is not that clear, so answer is just pointing in a direction.*

There are several ways to select the values / elements more specific - One option could be to select it by the name of the metric with selector `:-soup-contains()`

```
EPS= soup.select_one('#mainContent_updAddRatios div:-soup-contains("EPS (TTM)") .Number').text
```

or

```
Market_Cap= soup.select_one('#mainContent_updAddRatios div:-soup-contains("Market Cap") .Number').text
```

Alternative could be:

```
for i in soup.select('#mainContent_updAddRatios div:has(small)'):
    name = i.small.get_text(strip=True)
    metric = metric.text.strip() if (metric := i.select_one('.Number')) else i.p.text.strip()
    print(f'{name} of {Stock_Symbol} Crores is {metric}')

Output -->

Market Cap of SBIN Crores is 408791.83
CASA % of SBIN Crores is 45.4
No. of Shares of SBIN Crores is 892.46
P/E of SBIN Crores is 15.86
P/B of SBIN Crores is 1.67
Face Value of SBIN Crores is ₹ 1
Div. Yield of SBIN Crores is 0.87 %
Book Value (TTM) of SBIN Crores is 274.32
Net Interest Income of SBIN Crores is 110710
Cost To Income % of SBIN Crores is 53.6
Promoter Holding of SBIN Crores is 57.62 %
EPS (TTM) of SBIN Crores is 28.88
CAR % of SBIN Crores is 13.74
ROE of SBIN Crores is 9.31
ROCE of SBIN Crores is 6.49
Profit Growth of SBIN Crores is 40.88
```